# Quick way to see if object only has specific properties with values

Tags: javascript, object

At a point in my code, I have an object with two or six properties, and I need to know if there are a specific combination of values:

```
var myObject = {
  name: "John Smith",
  type = "person"
  prop1: "",
  prop2: "",
  prop3: "",
  prop4: ""
};
```

or

```
var myObject = {
  name: "My Business Name",
  type = "business"
};
```

I need to determine if the object has one of two conditions:

1. name has a value and type is "business"
2. name has a value, type is "person" and the other four properties have no value.

If it meets one of these two conditions, I put it in one place, otherwise I put it in another. As shown above, `if type == "business`, `prop1-prop4` don't exist in the object, but `if type == "person"`, they do.

What is a somewhat easy way to do this without having to specifically check `prop1 - prop 4` every time?

I'm looking through lodash functions to see if one (or more chained together) will do the trick, but I haven't identified one yet. I'm open to pure JS options, too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Checking for those conditions inside a function is one solution.   
var myObject = {
 name: "John Smith",
 type = "person"
 prop1: "",
 prop2: "",
 prop3: "",
 prop4: ""
};    
var validated = validateObject(myObject);
 function validateObject(obj){

   if((obj[name] &&  obj[type] === "business") || ((obj[name] &&  obj[type] === "person" && !obj[prop1] && !obj[prop2] && !obj[prop3] && !obj[prop4])) ){
    return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be the following one (which, in fact, uses vanilla JavaScript!):

```js
var myObject1 = {
  name: "John Smith",
  type: "person",
  prop1: "",
  prop2: "",
  prop3: "",
  prop4: ""
};

var myObject2 = {
  name: "My Business Name",
  type: "business"
};

doStuff(myObject1);
doStuff(myObject2);

function doStuff(obj) {
  var properties = Object.keys(obj);

  switch (obj.type) {
    case "person":
      if (["name", "prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop4"].every(p => properties.includes(p))) {
        // Do stuff with a valid person 
        console.log("This person is fine!");
      }
      break;

    case "business":
      if (properties.includes("name")) {
        // Do stuff with a valid business
        console.log("This business is fine!");
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What would be the ES5 way to do this? The platform I'm using doesn't support ES6 yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function and a single `if` condition

```js
var myObject = {
  name: "John Smith",
  type : "person",
  prop1: "",
  prop2: "",
  prop3: "",
  prop4: ""
};

var myObject1 = {
  name: "My Business Name",
  type: "business"
};

let checkProps = (obj, objName) => {
  let {name, type, prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4} = obj, len = name.length;
  if (len && type === "busines" || len && type === "person" 
      && prop1 + prop2 + prop3 + prop4 === "") {
    console.log(objName + " meets one of two conditions")
  } else {
    console.log(objName + " does not meet one of two conditions")
  }
}

checkProps(myObject, "myObject");

checkProps(myObject1, "myObject1");
```